# Force a derived-class object to use its own function, not the base-class one

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, object-slicing

I have some doubts about subclasses in C++. I have this code:

```
class BaseClass() {
    BaseClass();
    void doSomething();
}

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
    SubClass();
    void doSomething();
}
```

When I declare a BaseClass object that could be a SubClass I do it calling the sub constructor...

```
BaseClass foo = SubClass();
```

Then I need foo to use the doSomething() method of the derived class, but when I do it this way...

```
foo.doSomething();
```

It uses the parent class method instead of the derived one. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
foo.SubClass::doSomething();
```

Is there any way to do it or I'm forced to declare the object with "SubClass" type to make it use its own function?

Comment: `virtual void doSomething();`??

Comment: `BaseClass foo = SubClass();` -- `foo` is an object of type `BaseClass`, not `SubClass`. This is an example of **object slicing**. And marking `doSomething()` virtual would not change this.

Comment: Yes, as Pete Becker said it seems an object slicing problem, so making the function virtual doesn't solve the problem... The only way to solve this is to explicitly declare foo as SubClass type, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1: object slicing**

In your initialization

```
BaseClass foo = SubClass();
```

you create an anonymous temporary `SubClass` object and copy-construct a `BaseClass` object. This means that foo is and remains a `BaseClass` that is copied from a `SubClass`.

This is called [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). If the `baseClass` would have data members,  the corresponding data members of the subclass would be copied into it.  If `SubClass` would have additional data members, these would be lost.

If you want to work with `BaseClass` objects, but without loosing the members of their real type, whether base or derived, you need to use reference or pointers:

```
BaseClass *foo = new SubClass;  // foo is a base class pointer but points to a SubClass object. 

SubClass bar;  
BaseClass& foo2 = bar;          // foo2 is a base class REFERENCE which refers to a Subclass object
```

But, this is not sufficient.

**Problem 2: polymorphism**

If you'd now calling the method:

```
foo->doSomething();  
foo2.doSomething();
```

it would still be `BaseClass::doSomething()` that would be called, despite the real type of the object pointed/referred to.  That's because for normal member functions, the compiler tries to identify the function to call at compile time: and at compile it only knows the type of the pointer or reference.

To benefit from a polymorphic behavior, you also need to define the function as `virtual` as explained by [Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821773/3723423).  In this case, the compiler would generate code that with a little overhead is able to identify dynamically the type of the object and hence would call the correct version of the function exactly as you expect.

Note that if you have at least one virtual function in your base class, you'd better declare a virtual destructor for it.

Answer (score 2):

Use virtual and override:

```
class BaseClass() {
    BaseClass();
    virtual ~BaseClass() = default;
    virtual void doSomething();
}

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
    SubClass();
    void doSomething() override ;
}
```

edit: as Christophe said, use a virtual destructor as above.

Comment: Yep ! But beter foresee a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the `dosomeThing` method virtual in BaseClass, like

```
virtual void doSomething()
{
   ----
}
```

Comment: this concept of Object Oriented Programming is called Polymorphism